# Missing spacing above theorem name

Tags: spacing, theorems

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newtheoremstyle{pcap} % name
    {\topsep}                    % Space above
    {\topsep}                    % Space below
    {\upshape}                   % Body font
    {}                           % Indent amount
    {\scshape}                   % Theorem head font
    {.}                          % Punctuation after theorem head
    {.2em}                       % Space after theorem head
    {}  % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
\theoremstyle{pcap}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{thm}[definition]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemmaen}[definition]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[definition]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Appendix}

foo

bar

\begin{proposition}foo
\end{proposition}

bar

\begin{definition}foo
\end{definition}

\begin{proof}bar
\end{proof}

foo

\begin{definition}bar
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

produces no vertical spacing before Theorem and Definition. Why does this happen? If \theoremstyle{plain} is used, the spacing is fine (except for the fact that it is not exactly the same above and below). How can I make this new style work?

[image]

Comment: Did you try commenting `\usepackage{parskip}`? `;-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `parskip` package sets `\topsep` to zero, so you get what you were asking for. `;-)`

The output in your picture was generated with `\theoremstyle{pcap}`, not with `\theoremstyle{plain}`.

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{parskip}

\newtheoremstyle{pcap} % name
 {\glueexpr\parskip*2\relax} % Space above
 {\parskip}                  % Space below
 {\upshape}                  % Body font
 {}                          % Indent amount
 {\scshape}                  % Theorem head font
 {.}                         % Punctuation after theorem head
 {.2em}                      % Space after theorem head
 {}  % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
\theoremstyle{pcap}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{thm}[definition]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemmaen}[definition]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[definition]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Appendix}

foo

bar

\begin{proposition}foo
\end{proposition}

bar

\begin{definition}foo
\end{definition}

\begin{proof}bar
\end{proof}

foo

\begin{definition}bar
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, my advice is to leave `parskip` out of the business. In my opinion, you just get ugly white strips across the page, with no benefit for the reader.

Comment: Thank you! I get no spacing even commenting the line \usepackage{parskip}. It seems that it has also to do with amsbook..

Comment: Btw, why do you need to multiply parskip by 2 to define the space above?

Comment: @Mizar I don't *need* to; it's for giving more room to the theorem statement.